# Update fancybox plugin from v 1.2.5 to latest - v 2.1.5

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've just made a pre-existing website responsive through CSS.

The only thing that is not right is an outdated 'fancybox' javascript plugin that is used to look at product images.

If you look at this page on a re-sized browser, you'll see that it doesn't resize properly. I tried to force it to resize in the CSS, but none of the settings would make any difference:

http://www.combataustralia.com.au/compound-bow/martin-blade-x4-gold-series/

I assumed that the only way to fix this is to update the plugin, but I see that there is no 'fancybox.js' file (which is what the template is using in the current site).

Just wondering what I need to do to install the plugin properly and make sure nothing breaks.

OR,even better - is there something easier (like CSS) that I just am not seeing...?

Thanks!

Comment: There is view-source:http://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/r-6d37b76e95d27e08de96485fb25c173a6327a992/javascript/jquery/plugins/fancybox/fancybox.js that you may need to deleted from the template before installing the newer version

Comment: Yes, I thought I would need to replace all of the contents of the 'fancybox' folder with the updated files. I'm just not sure how to make sure i don't 'break' the functionality of the plugin in the site since 'fancybox.js' won't exist anymore...?

Is there a simpler solution?